# Design Lab for students

Tags: education

As a part time instructor, I was given a design lab that I would create and implement for students. For acceleration due to gravity that is not replicating overused labs related to measuring period vs length, angle or mass, please advise.

Comment: Sand in the laboratory is a nasty thing. Make sure you get a good vacuum and the students are required to keep the place clean, otherwise it's going to be a mess. The other problem is that you are looking at a hard to analyze physical situation. The solution for a linear chirp are Fresnel integrals, which is OK for a EE major who wants to do communications systems to deal with, but they really don't mean much to a physicist. The error propagation in this experiment is tough, sand does not run smoothly trough a hole and it depends strongly on moisture content. I would do something else instead.

Comment: With enough budget and mechanics shop support you could do a pendulum in a centrifuge. Lot's of good stuff that you can do with pseudoforces. :-)

Comment: This is way too broad of a question to be feasibly answered here. Basically anything that involves gravity would be a valid answer, meaning that there really isn't *one* answer that we prefer in this Q&A website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of one entertaining variation on a pendulum, and that's the ballistic pendulum. Make a stationary pendulum with a rigid connecting rod (no rope). Arrange for an impact with a horizontally moving body of known mass and velocity. Vary the momentum of the impactor until the pendulum does a perfect (or as close as feasible) 180 degree swing. When it pauses at the top, you know that $\frac{m{v^2}}{2} = mgh$. Since $h = 2R$ you can calculate g if you know v. And you can include the effects of either an elastic or inelastic collision in determining v. Since the pendulum weight is stationary at both top and bottom of the path, rotational effects are not in play.

Note that this does not depend either on mass or angle. Of course, it doesn't teach anything about the more common variety of pendulum, but I just thought I'd offer it.

It will let you determine g.

EDIT - Rather than using an impact, you might do something like have a cart carry the pendulum weight at a known speed. Have the pendulum rod somehow hook onto the weight and lift it off the cart. I'm hesitant about this approach, since it would be necessary to provide a fairly sophisticated hook arrangement to keep the weight aligned to the arm during motion. But it would get around the necessity of calculating collision dynamics.

END EDIT

Comment: I've never seen one used that way. Google on "ballistic pendulum". You'd want to produce a known horizontal velocity for your impactor (a voltage-controlled DC motor driving a car on a horizontal track, for instance). Make the impactor and the pendulum weight out of steel for good elasticity on impact. The data would be a single point - adjust the impactor velocity until the pendulum does a perfect half-loop. Then calculate the velocity imparted to the pendulum weight, and thence the kinetic energy.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanations. It really does help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that the period of the pendulum is describable by the formula you have above, there will be no effect.  The reason is that the restoring force (i.e., the force of gravity in the tangential direction) is $F_\theta = - m(t) g \sin \theta$, and so Newton's second law (in polar coordinates) yields $m(t) l \ddot{\theta} = - m(t) g \sin \theta$, or $\ddot{\theta} = - (g/l) \sin \theta \approx -(g/l) \theta$ for small theta.  The mass cancels out, and the period stays constant.

Now, if you actually do this experiment, you'll actually get a small effect due to a couple of factors.  First off, as the sand empties out, the center of mass and the moment of inertia about the pivot will change, causing a small shift in the frequency.  This would be equivalent to just changing $l$ as the oscillation progresses, though;  so if this is the effect you want to see, you might as well just change the length of the string directly.

Second, you might actually see an effect because of air resistance.  If the cross-sectional area of the bag stays roughly the same, there will be a constant force retarding the pendulum's motion, and so you'll probably see some effects.  But these are due to physical phenomena that are present (but neglected) in the original pendulum setup, and that are very difficult to model accurately.  In other words, the experiment you describe is really more of a measurement of air resistance of an object.  If you're just after a measurement of $g$, this is not the way to do it;  and if you're looking to measure the air resistance of an object, there are much, much, much better ways to do it.

Comment: The effective length of the pendulum will change, so there is an effect, but I agree that it's a poorly conceived experiment.

Comment: @mathphd it is possible to find $g$ using a circular disc spinning around axis different distances from the centre, but I don't know if you would count a spinning disc as a pendulum?

Comment: @CuriousOne:  thanks for the correction.  I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for the thorough answer that you've so kindly given. I think I'll decide on a change of ideas for this design lab. Any ideas based on my parameters?

Comment: Take the pendulum apparatus to the roof of your building.  Drop it off and time how long it takes to hit the ground.  Then $g = 2 \Delta x/t^2$.  (I'm joking.  Mostly.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good Idea, but may get me in trouble haha :) Thanks for your input nevertheless and for guiding me to seek a more appropriate lab for the students.

Comment: If you can't "do the overused experiment where the independent variable will be either length, angle, or mass", just what else is there to use? I know you're being given directions, but that one doesn't make sense.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Same here, that's why I'm so confused :) I have been advised that my experiment needs to go beyond the standard pendulum experiment of length vs period for the students. I'm trying to formulate an experiment that's different, but still shows acceleration due to gravity (g) from a pendulum, but I'm running in a road block as to how.

Comment: Can you reliably measure the amplitude of the oscillations as a function of time?  If so, you could do a measurement of the [_Q_ factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/Q_factor) of the pendulum, which is a useful quantity that real-world engineers and scientists actually use.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thanks for the input. I probably could do an experiment of the Q factor. Unfortunately, since I have only recently begun working with students in Physics, I find myself having to catch up much of the time being primarily a mathematics tutor. As thus, I would need to see an example of such an experiment being worked out and if possible, see a procedure, data table/analysis, etc., After that, I can probably make a design and present it to the students. Definitely a great idea, do you have any web links to a completed lab or procedure, etc.,? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a circular disc, one cut out of cardboard will do.

Place a series of small holes along one diameter.

For a disc mass $M$ the moment of inertia, through the centre, is $I=0.5Ma^2$ where $a$ is its radius of the disc.

For an axis a distance $x$ away from the center (the axis can be created with e.g. some dowel thru one of the holes). The equation of motion is given by: 
$$(0.5Ma^2+Mx^2)\ddot  \theta\approx-Mgx\theta$$
which implies:
$$\ddot \theta \approx -\frac{gx}{0.5a^2+x^2}\theta$$
This has a period of:

$$T\approx 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{0.5a^2}{gx}+\frac{x}{g}}$$
Thus if you plot $T^2$ against $\frac{0.5a^2}{x}+x$ you will get a straight line graph with gradient equal to $4\pi^2/g$.

But thinking about it, this is just a fancy way of changing the length of the pendulum. 
[image]

Comment: @mathphd see edit for picture, the variable $M$ is  the total mass of the disc, $a$ is the radius and $x$ is the distance of the axis from the centre of mass (which can be found using e.g. a plumb bob)

Comment: You have not been much help -